# How can i implement multiselect with DropDown using swift 5?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift5

Here is the current action of single selection , please suggest a way to implement multiple selection using DropDown, my Xcode version is 10

```
empProfLeaveDropDown.selectionAction = { [unowned self] (index: Int, item: String) in
             print("Selected item: \(item) at index: \(index)")
             self.leaveTypeLabel1.text = item
    }
```

[image: Image for above code]

Comment: It looks like some custom UIView, was it written by you or it's from dependency library? If latter, please specify which one.

Comment: It is from the DropDown library, from this github repo https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown @user28434

Comment: Ok, it looks like you gotta create a `set` and insert/remove items there on `selectionAction`

Comment: Yea, that's right, but how to select multiple options in the DropDown source.....?

Comment: You'll have to deal with the library code, maybe add an extension for the component. Also, even if multiple options from the list, how does the user know "how to confirm", and also right after, how do you display visually that multiple options have been selected? Don't think only about what's stopping you right now, but also think about the next steps as they can affect the code you need now. Good luck with it and don't forget to add the answer if you find it to help the community